# Why the linearization $(1+u\left(x\right))^k \approx 1+ku\left(x\right)$ is eligible to use when $u\left(x\right)\approx0$?

Tags: calculus, functions, linearization

I know, that applying *standard linear approximation* to $(1+x)^k$ at $0$ for any real k results in $1+kx$. However while reading *Thomas' Calculus 14th Ed.*, in section 3.9 I encountered many examples using this approximation for values of $x$ near $0$ such as:
$$\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \approx 1+{1\over2}x^2 \tag{1}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{1+5x^4} \approx 1+{1\over3}(5x^4) \tag{2}\label{2}$$

I saw many such examples on YouTube also. Let me work through the second example. I understand that for $x\approx0$, $5x^4$ is also approximately equal to zero and because of that one may fall into substituting $x$ in $1+kx$ with $5x^4$ and using it in approximation. But when I find the value of the derivative of \eqref{2} $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sqrt[3]{1+5x^4}={1\over3}\left(1+5x^4\right)^{-2/3}(20x^3)$$ it's value at $x=0$ is $0$. Thus, applying *std linear approximation* to \eqref{2} near $0$ I get that it is approximately equal to $1+0x=1$. Hence, $1$ is the *best* linear approximation for \eqref{2}.

Why it is then many examples use the first approximation even when instead of $x$ there is some function of $x$ being used?

Comment: $(1+u)^k \approx 1+ku$ holds regardless of what $u$ is exactly as long as it is small. It doesn't result in a linear-in-$x$ approximation if $u$ is a nonlinear function of $x$. If $u$ is much smaller than $x$ for small $x$, then the linear approximation of $(1+u)^k$ will just be $1$, as in your examples.

Comment: @Ian Maybe it holds, but I did not understand the reason behind it.

Comment: @Ian Well, 5x^4 is much smaller than x when x is near 0. But why then most examples do not use just 1 instead of 1+kx? Apart from that can you give me the reference where I can find that (1+u)^k approximately equal to 1+ku where u is a function of x?

Comment: The *linear* approximation in that example is indeed just $1$. But generally people want to capture something better than a constant approximation, even for something that is varying relatively slowly.

Comment: Note that the linearisation of the expression in the title is $(1+u(x))^k \approx 1+ k u'(0) x$ (I am assuming that $u(0) = 0$). In your example, $u'(0) = 0$ so the linearisation is $\approx 1$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, that is what I actually thought i.e (derivative at 0 is 0). I was just bothered why examples do not take this into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $1 + \tfrac{1}{3}(5x^4)$ is the **the** fourth order Taylor polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{1+5x^4}$ around $x=0$.

The Taylor series of a composition of functions such as $f(g(x))$ around $a$ can be found by plugging in the Taylor series of $g(x)$ around $a$ into the Taylor series of $f(x)$ around $g(a)$.

In your case we have
$$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{1+x},$$
$$g(x) = 5x^4,$$
$$f(g(x)) = \sqrt[3]{1+5x^4}$$
and we are interested in the Taylor series of $f(g(x))$ around $0$.

Taking the Taylor series of both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ around $0$ gives:
$$f(x) = 1 + \tfrac{1}{3}x - \tfrac{1}{9}x^2 + \cdots,$$
$$g(x) = 5x^4,$$
where for $g(x)$ you can use the handy fact that The Taylor series of any polynomial is the polynomial itself.
Plugging now the Taylor of $g(x)$ into $f(x)$ gives:
$$f(g(x)) =  1 + \tfrac{1}{3}5x^4 - \tfrac{1}{9}(5x^4)^2 + \cdots,$$
Which we can truncate to
$$f(g(x)) \approx 1 + \tfrac{1}{3}5x^4.$$

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure is it correct.
but i think L'hospital rule may be useful.
consider $\lim_{x\to0}{[1+u(x)]^k-1\over 1+ku(x)-1}=\lim_{x\to0}{k[1+u(x)]^{k-1}u'(x)\over ku'(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}[1+u(x)]^{k-1}=1$ that's what we want.

i hope it would help

Comment: hi, I think this does not answer the question

Comment: I guess you wanted to say that these two functions (...^k and 1+kx) behave similarly for very small values of x i.e when $x\approx0$. Even if it is so how you managed to cancel $u'(x)$ when nothing said whether it is 0 or not for x near 0.

Comment: yep, i want to show 1+u(x)^k  approximately equal to 1+kx when x and u(x) approximately equal to zero. u'(x) would be devided if it is not zero.hmmm....we can use L'hospital rule again if it is 0. or till the nth derivative is not 0.

Comment: Any way, i like the solution of Taylor expansion,you can find the Taylor series of 1+u(x)^k is 1+ku'(x).so linear approximation will be better as u'(x) is small,of course it will be the best when u'(x)=0